# How did Mazikeen end up with Lucifer at the "Lux"?

Tags: comics, the-sandman, vertigo-comics, lucifer

In *The Sandman* Vol. 4. Chapter 1 (#23), we see that when Lucifer seals the gates of hell, he bids goodbye to Mazikeen (a demon of hell, with half her face horribly disfigured) and says:

> Mazikeen: You may not go with me. I am sorry. I do not know where I am going, but wherever I go, I will be travelling alone.

Followed by the awesomely disgusting kiss, he says again:

> It is enough for me to know that you care for me, Mazikeen. I thank you.
>
> Now go.
>
> Goodbye, Mazikeen.
>
> You are very beautiful.

Here it seems that Lucifer has bid the final goodbye to Mazikeen.

And then in Vol. 9. *The Kindly Ones*: 1(#57), we see a mute waitress with a half mask, who, I am quite sure, is Mazikeen hiding the skinless rotten left half of face.

My question is, is there any mention anywhere in series (or any canon material) explaining how she end up with Lucifer?

Answer (score 4):

It was explained in the [Lucifer spinoff comic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_%28DC_Comics%29) that Mazikeen left Hell and followed Lucifer to Lux (the piano bar he opened in Los Angeles).

That's explicitly called out on [her Wikipedia page (warning: spoilers!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazikeen_%28comics%29):

> When Lucifer resigned, Mazikeen left Hell and ended up following her master, becoming part of the staff at the "Lux" (Latin for light), an elite Los Angeles bar that Lucifer had opened and at which he played piano. ...

Comment: Your answer is acceptable, but I was looking for an explanation on what made Lucifer change his mind to allow Mazikeen to follow him. In #23 we clearly see that Lucifer clearly doesn't allow Mazikeen to follow him and says Good Bye.

Comment: I've read that comic, and it's not explained anywhere in it. She just pops up in _The Kindly Ones_ and then hangs on.